# В чем отличие ошибки и исключения в js?

Tags: javascript, исключения

В "Инструментах разработчика" есть инструмент `pause on exceptions`, но как я вижу, "пауза" срабатывает и просто перед какой-то обычной ошибкой (не определена переменная, например).

Так в чем отличие исключения и ошибки? Что вообще может считаться за исключение? И может ли что-нибудь в одно и то же самое время быть как исключением, так и ошибкой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете считать их синонимами.

Ошибки бывают уровня пользователя (вызванные авторами скрипта или библиотеки на тех местах, где их что-то не удовлетворяет, при помощи `throw`) и уровня языка. Ошибки уровня языка могут быть вызваны ещё во время разбора вашего кода (ошибка синтаксиса, например) или во время его исполнения.

Читайте подробнее, например, здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/error-handling